# WiX: Patching a patch no longer works after upgrading from WiX 3.0 to WiX 3.6-8

Tags: wix, patch

I have a set of WiX scripts that used to allow me to create patches for patches, e.g. I would have full installers for the following version numbers:

11.00.38.01
11.00.38.02
11.00.38.03

I would then create patches between these numbers, i.e.

11.00.38.01-11.00.38.02
11.00.38.02-11.00.38.03

Using these scripts with WiX 3.0 I would be able to run

11.00.38.01

and then apply the

11.00.38.01-11.00.38.02 and 11.00.38.02-11.00.38.03 patches,

which would bring the installation up to

11.00.38.03

After upgrading to WiX 3.6 and later 3.7 and 3.8, this no longer works.

I can install one build and apply one patch to that build but I cannot install a build, patch the installation, and then apply another patch.

If I attempt to do that, I get the following error:

> The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service
>   because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade
>   patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the
>   program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the
>   correct upgrade patch.

My patch template looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch
        AllowRemoval="no"
        Manufacturer="Acme"
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.acme.com/"
        DisplayName="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion) Upgrade"
        Description="Minor Upgrade"
        Classification="Update"
    >

        <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM"/>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="$(var.ProductShortName)UpgradeFamily"/>
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>
        <PatchFamily Id='$(var.ProductShortName)UpgradeFamily' Version='1.0.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id='PatchComponents' />
        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Part of the .wxs script for the product looks like this:

```
<Product Name='Acme Server'
    Id='6DE00366-36D8-4BA0-B911-8FBD7490C472'
    UpgradeCode='0FDE99AC-D910-46CF-814D-D851B81D3816'
    Language='1033'
    Codepage='1252'
    Version='$(var.ProductVersion)'
    Manufacturer='Acme'>
    <Package
        Id='*'
        Keywords='Installer'
        Description="Acme Server"
        Comments='Acme Server is a registered trademark of Acme.'
        Manufacturer='Acme'
        InstallerVersion='200'
        Languages='0'
        Compressed='yes'
        SummaryCodepage='1252'
        Platform='x86'
    />

    <Upgrade Id='0FDE99AC-D910-46CF-814D-D851B81D3816'>
        <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='SELFFOUND'
            Minimum='$(var.ProductVersion)' IncludeMinimum='yes' Maximum='$(var.ProductVersion)' IncludeMaximum='yes' />
        <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='NEWERFOUND'
            Minimum='$(var.ProductVersion)' IncludeMinimum='no' />
    </Upgrade>
</Product>
```

The interesting thing is that the WiX 3.0 patch log contains the following line:

> PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of minor upgrade patch
>   c:\Install\10.10.11.01-10.10.11.02\AcmeServer.msp against product
>   code: {6DE00366-36D8-4BA0-B911-8FBD7490C472}, product version:
>   10.10.1101, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {0FDE99AC-D910-46CF-814D-D851B81D3816}

whereas the WiX 3.6+ patch log contains this line:

> PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of QFE patch
>   c:\11.00.38.01-11.00.38.02\AcmeServer.msp against product code:
>   {6DE00366-36D8-4BA0-B911-8FBD7490C472}, product version: 11.00.3801,
>   product language 1033 and upgrade code:
>   {0FDE99AC-D910-46CF-814D-D851B81D3816}

Notice that the 3.0 log says "minor upgrade patch" whereas the 3.6+ log says "QFE patch". I do not know if this is relevant here.

What could I be doing wrong here? Why did the behavior of the generated patches change? Of course, there have been minor tweaks to the WiX scripts over the past couple of years but as far as I know none of them were related to the patching process. It seems as if the main change was due to the switch from WiX 3.0 to a newer version.

EDIT:

I have verified that this change happened exactly at the time I switched from WiX 3.0 to WiX 3.6.

I have also noticed that if I apply the WiX 3.0-generated patches, the version number *is* updated in Programs & Features when a patch is applied to a full installation or another patch whereas with the WiX 3.6+-generated patches, the version number stays the same when a patch is applied to a full installation.

I am wondering if any defaults have changed for the command-line tools (torch, pyro, etc)?

Comment: My guess is that it's something to do with PackageCodes. The difference between a QFE and a minor upgrade is about if the PackageCode has changed. The other clue is that the identity of an installed product is (ProductCode+PackageCode), and the patch has a target packagecode that it cannot find on the system. So some combination of patches has changed the packagecode of the product and some haven't.

Comment: Patches generated using WiX 3.0 will update the version number in Programs & Featues. If generated by WiX 3.6+, the version number is not updated (though in both cases the files are being updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a ProductVersion property reference to the PatchFamily element as seen in the snippet below:

```
<Fragment>
    <PatchFamily Id='$(var.ProductShortName)UpgradeFamily' Version='1.0.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
        <PropertyRef Id="ProductVersion"/>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='PatchComponents' />
    </PatchFamily>
</Fragment>
```

That was all there was to it.

I do not see this mentioned in any of the documentation or the usual, old sample patch script found on the web, though now that I know what to look for, it is easy enough to find discussions about it.

As I mentioned in my original question, this element was not necessary when using WiX 3.0 which might go some way to explain its absence from the old patch sample.